# can anyone help me out ? my foreach loop for all buttons in form is not working. there is some kind of bug c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to compare values of tableno column with Button.Text in form. There are 50 buttons on the forms. the idea is if tableno = button.text then button color must change. so i have written this function which i am calling on form load. but its not working. there is not error or exception. Also logically this code seems to be ok.
      My code isn't able to recognize buttons on form. it just couldn't enter into for each loop. it gets out of the loop.button color is not changing.
can anyone help for this ?

```
 public void checktablenoandchangebtncolor()   
 {
           //  List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT tableno FROM kottemp ", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader ;
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
           // string value = command.ExecuteScalar() as string;

             while (reader.Read())
             {
             foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
              {
             if (ctrl is Button)

              {
               if (ctrl.Text == reader["tableno"].ToString())
                {
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
                  }
              else
                 {
                 ctrl.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                  }
                   }
             }
       }
             reader.Close();
            con.Close()
 }
```

Comment: Maybe the buttons are not placed directly on form and they are children of a panel or something else. If this is the case, use `Controls` property of the container that contains buttons, for example `panel1.Controls` instead of `this.Controls`.

Comment: Did you debug the code and check if it executes first if block?

Comment: The problem is your code has bad logic.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes i did...!!

Comment: @RezaAghaei your tip helped me to complete this taks.. thank u :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's get you an extension methods:

```
public static class MyExtensions {
  public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(this Control control)
  {
    foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
    {
      yield return c;
      foreach (Control c1 in c.GetAllControls())
        yield return c1;
      }
    }
  }
  public static IEnumerable<T> GetList(this SqlConnection con, string query)
  {
    con.Open();
    using(var cmd=new SqlCommand(query,con))
    using(var dr=cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
      while(dr.Read())
      {
        yield return (T)dr[0];
      }
    }
    con.Close();
  }
}
```

This would be a lot easier if the button texts were guaranteed to be unique (or only a few hundred controls on the form), but since I can't just assume that, I used lookups instead of a dictionary like this:

```
public void checktablenoandchangebtncolor()   
{

  var btns = this.GetAllControls()
    .OfType<Button>()
    .ToLookup(x=>x.Text, x=>x);

  /* Turn all buttons grey */
  foreach(var btn in btns.SelectMany(x=>x))
  {
    btn.BackColor = Color.Grey;
  }

  using(var con = new SqlConnection(...))
  {
    var query = "SELECT tableno FROM kottemp";
    foreach(var key in con.GetList<string>(query));
    {
      foreach(var btn in btns[key])
      {
        btn.BackColor = Color.Red;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't have many records in your table and you don't mind including [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) in your project you could simplify it like so:

```
public void checktablenoandchangebtncolor()   
{
  var btns = this.GetAllControls()
    .OfType<Button>();

  using(var con = new SqlConnection(...))
  {
    var query = "SELECT tableno FROM kottemp";
    var list = con.Query<string>(query);

    foreach(var btn in btns)
    {
      btn.BackColor = list.Contains(btn.Text)
        ? Color.Red
        : Color.Grey;
    }
  }
}
```